# Typescript - Compiled Constants

Tags: node.js, typescript

Here is the scenario:
I have some code that works like this:

```
const noteProcess:Process = new ProcessBuilder<Note>().addSteps(...).build();
export function processNote(note:Note):Promise<Note>{
    return noteProcess.process(note);
}
```

Is there a way to force the above `constant` to compile/transpile down to the final product and not on init? There is nothing in there to suggest being any difference between runs.

Comment: If you want this behavior, it might be worth looking into community plugins for other, extensible transpilers (e.g. Babel).

Answer (score 1):

If TypeScript evaluated your source like the JS runtime VM does, then yes, it would be possible, but `tsc` doesn't execute your code.

This is for good reason: this would cause potential side-effects (like running impure or non-idempotent ops every time compilation happened).

---

The exception to this is [`const` enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums), which are a TypeScript compiler-specific feature (not a runtime feature).